# Oracle Passing Custom Table Type To Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, custom-type

**FYI:** Oracle 12c

I have created a custom type called `Payeezy_Error`:

```
create or replace TYPE PAYEEZY_ERROR
AS

  OBJECT (
    CODE VARCHAR(30),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200)
  );
```

And then in turn created a Table type of `Payeezy_Errors`:

```
create or replace TYPE PAYEEZY_ERRORS AS TABLE OF PAYEEZY_ERROR;
```

I then have a Procedure that takes `Payeezy_Errors` as an `IN` parameter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SAVE_USER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION
(
  in_AccountID         IN VARCHAR2,
  in_SequenceID        IN VARCHAR2,
  in_CorrelationID     IN VARCHAR2,
  in_TransactionID     IN VARCHAR2,
  in_TransactionTag    IN VARCHAR2,
  in_Currency          IN VARCHAR2,
  in_TransactionType   IN VARCHAR2,
  in_BankResponse      IN VARCHAR2,
  in_GatewayResponse   IN VARCHAR2,
  in_ValidationStatus  IN VARCHAR2,
  in_TransactionStatus IN VARCHAR2,
  in_Errors            IN PAYEEZY_ERRORS
)
AS

  var_uptID NUMBER;
  var_ErrorCount NUMBER := 0;

  EX_AUTHENTICATION EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

  -- Insert the Payeezy Response values tied to the user
  INSERT INTO
    USER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION (
      ACCOUNT_ID,         UP_PAYMENT_SEQ_ID,   CORRELATION_ID,       TRANSACTION_ID,
      TRANSACTION_TAG,    CURRENCY,            TRANSACTION_TYPE,     BANK_RESPONSE,
      GATEWAY_RESPONSE,   VALIDATION_STATUS,   TRANSACTION_STATUS
    ) VALUES (
      in_AccountID,       in_SequenceID,       in_CorrelationID,     in_TransactionID,
      in_TransactionTag,  in_Currency,         in_TransactionType,   in_BankResponse,
      in_GatewayResponse, in_ValidationStatus, in_TransactionStatus
    )
  RETURNING
    ID
  INTO
    var_uptID;

  -- Insert any errors that may be associated with a failure/unsuccessful transaction
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  INTO
    var_ErrorCount
  FROM
    in_Errors;

  IF (var_ErrorCount > 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO
      USER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR (
        UPT_ID, CODE, DESCRIPTION
      )
    SELECT
      var_uptID, e.CODE, e.DESCRIPTION
    FROM
      in_Errors;
  END IF;


  -- Exception Handling
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN EX_AUTHENTICATION THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Authentication Failed.');

END SAVE_USER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION;
```

When I compile the procedure it yells at me at the `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement that:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
```

And red-dashes are under `SELECT` and `in_Errors`.

Further down the procedure I get the same error and the second `INSERT INTO` and `in_Errors` lines are red-dashes too.

I have exited and reloaded Oracle SQL Developer just to see if it was a caching thing.  I have searched around the web but have not found my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the table in a query, you'd need to use the `table` operator

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  INTO
    var_ErrorCount
  FROM
    table( in_Errors );
```

That works.  But it means that you're taking all of the data that you have in the PL/SQL collection, moving it to the SQL VM, doing the aggregation, and then returning the result to PL/SQL.  It would likely be more efficient (and less code) in this case to just do

```
var_ErrorCount := in_Errors.count;
```

Comment: Seeing is I am a SQL Server guy, I will take your recommendation and change the code as well.  Thanks!